# React Router v4 Redirect fails to redirect

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router-v4

With `onEnter` replaced with `render` I changed my code to match the router v4 specs. The point was to prevent the `/signup` page from getting displayed when logged in.What do i miss in my code?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import browserHistory from 'history';
import {Tracker} from 'meteor/tracker';

import Signup from '../imports/ui/Signup';
import MyLink from '../imports/ui/MyLink';
import NotFound from '../imports/ui/NotFound';
import Login from '../imports/ui/Login';

const history = browserHistory.createBrowserHistory();

const unathenticatedPages = ['/', '/signup'];
const athenticatedPages = ['/mylink'];
const onEnterPublicPage = () => {
  if (Meteor.userId()) {
    return <Redirect to="/mylink/" />;
  }
};

const routes = (
  <BrowserRouter history={history}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Login} render={() => onEnterPublicPage} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} render={() => onEnterPublicPage} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/mylink" component={MyLink} />
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

Tracker.autorun(() => {
  const isAuthenticated = !!Meteor.userId();    
  const pathname = history.location.pathname;

  const isUnathenticatedPage = unathenticatedPages.includes(pathname);
  const isAthenticatedPage = athenticatedPages.includes(pathname);

  if (isAuthenticated && isUnathenticatedPage) {
    history.push('/mylink');
  } else if (!isAuthenticated && isAthenticatedPage) {
    history.push('/');
  }
});

Meteor.startup(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With React Router 4, you no longer use Browserhistory like that. Instead, it is included in the BrowserRouter, like you see [in the documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start).

Also, I am not sure if this will solve what's going on, but I make an `App` component and I put my routing in there. Then, with v4, the history comes through in `props`. Then you can run your logic and do `props.history.push(url)`.

**Edit**: Here is the code I have used to get this to work:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import BinsList from './bins/BinsList';
import BinsMain from './bins/BinsMain';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={BinsList}></Route>
          <Route path="/bins/:binId" component={BinsMain}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And my header is rendered like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Accounts from './Accounts';
import { Link, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'


class Header extends Component {
  onBinClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    Meteor.call('bins.insert', (err, bin) => {
      const url = `/bins/${bin}`;
      this.props.history.push(url);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="nav navbar-default">
        <div className="navbar-header">
          <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">MarkBin</Link>
        </div>
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <Accounts />
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" onClick={this.onBinClick.bind(this)}>Create Bin</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Header);
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please fix the doc link? It leads to the beginning of the documentation

Comment: That was actually intentional because right in the installation section at the beginning, it shows how to use the BrowserRouter. But if it's helpful, here is a link to BrowserRouter: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter

Comment: I removed `history={history}` from `<BrowserRouter ...></BrowserRouter>`. The `history` object gets accessed in the `MyLink` component like this `this.props.history.push('/login');`. The app seems continue to work correctly. Is this what you referred to concerning the use of BrowserRouter?

Comment: Yes! That is what I was referring to. Is it working as expected now?

Comment: BrowserRouter doesn't seem to push the `history` instance to the components when those are inside `render()`. Do you have ideas how to fix that? I managed to push `history` to an actual component as shown in the code below but when clicking the button there is no page redirect.

Comment: Building your routes variable the way that you did is reminiscent of React Router v3. It will still work, but the way that Tyler McGinnis, one of the creators of it, teaches it is to put your routes inside of a main component, (e.g., `App`) and then the history is inside of that component's props. If that still doesn't work, you can always export that component `withRouting`. I have added my code that works like this above.

Comment: I prolly haven't reached that far in the course yet. However I ended up exporting the `MyLink` component with `withRouter`. Thank you for a useful example it'll help to ease the understanding of React in the near future.
How the use of `this.props.history.push(url);` is possible inside `Header`?  Is it somehow called from `App` only?
How does `withRouter` allow of use of `this.props.history` in a component even if `history` was never imported in that component?

Answer (score 0):

Almost works now with the changes:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import browserHistory from 'history';
import {Tracker} from 'meteor/tracker';

import Signup from '../imports/ui/Signup';
import MyLink from '../imports/ui/MyLink';
import NotFound from '../imports/ui/NotFound';
import Login from '../imports/ui/Login';

const history = browserHistory.createBrowserHistory();

const unathenticatedPages = ['/', '/signup'];
const athenticatedPages = ['/mylink'];
const isLoggedIn = () => {
  return Meteor.userId() !== null;
};

const routes = (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch >
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => (isLoggedIn() ? <Redirect to="/mylink"/> : <Login/>)} />
      <Route path="/signup" render={() => (isLoggedIn() ? <Redirect to="/mylink"/> : <Signup/>)} />
      <Route path="/login" render={() => (isLoggedIn() ? <Redirect to="/mylink"/> : <Login/>)} />
      <Route path="/mylink" render={() => (!isLoggedIn() ? <Login/> : <MyLink history={history}/>)} />
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

Tracker.autorun(() => {
  const isAuthenticated = !!Meteor.userId();
  console.log("isAuthenticated: ", isAuthenticated);

  const pathname = history.location.pathname;
  console.log("pathname: ", pathname);

  const isUnathenticatedPage = unathenticatedPages.includes(pathname);
  const isAthenticatedPage = athenticatedPages.includes(pathname);

  if (isLoggedIn() && isUnathenticatedPage) {
    history.replace('/mylink');
  } else if (!isLoggedIn() && isAthenticatedPage) {
    history.replace('/');
  }
});

Meteor.startup(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

The MyLink.js component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Accounts} from 'meteor/accounts-base';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

class MyLink extends React.Component {    
  navigate(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push('/notfound');
  }

  onLogout() {
    Accounts.logout();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>MyLink</p>
        <button onClick={this.navigate.bind(this)}>Go to Not Found page</button>
        <br/>
        <button onClick={this.onLogout.bind(this)}>Log out</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(MyLink);
```

Comment: Instead of having a button with a click event that tries to push a url to the history, just use the React Router v4 Link tag: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

Comment: Thank you. It was a tutorial I followed here. I was curious if there was a way to add properties to rendered components when they are inside `render()`. It seems there is none.