# React Route V4 history has pushed but the page was not redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I try to use React Route V4 to build the route of app.

as following:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createHistory();    
<Provider store= {store}>
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <Router history={history}>
            <div>
                    <LayoutContainer/>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/records" render={() =>{
                return (<DealsContainer/>)
          }}/>
          <Route path="/sign_in" component={SignInContainer}/>
            </div>
          </Router>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
```

I compared the method `this.props.history.push('/')` and `history.push("/")`, I find their is different way when I put it to different lifecycle method.

```
//dealsContainer.js    
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from '../_helpers/history';

componentDidMount(){
 //history.push("/sign_in");                  //browser url will change but no redirect
//this.props.history.push("/sign_in");            //it work
}
render(){
 if(this.props.authenticate.LoggedIn == false){
  //this.props.history.push("/sign_in");          // it work
  //history.push("/sign_in");                     // it work
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return{
  deals: state.deals,
  authenticate: state.authenticate,
 }
};
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(DealsContainer))
```

And the `history.push("/")` in the `asyncActions` function was not working.
Does it possible to let it work in asyncActions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router v4 Redirect Failing to Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086572/react-router-v4-redirect-fails-to-redirect)

Comment: @brandNew I try the official solution, I got the info `You are now at /records` but my browser url was updating to `/sign_in`

Comment: with react router v4, you have to make use of `withRouter` as shown here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter and access the history from props

Comment: @Panther Yeah, I used it to wrap my export default like `export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(RecrodsContainer))`

Comment: I tried to use `this.props.history.push("/")` instead of `history` module `history.push("/")`, and It work, but why?

Comment: I found the error, the history module should be used in same import , it should not use by calling module individually

Comment: The description of the tag `history` starts with "DO NOT USE THIS TAG" (yes, in CAPITALS for CLARITY). So don't use it.